# Need to setup ubuntu server files secure

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, samba, file-sharing

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 server. On that we have some projects which are shared with Samba share. I need to protect our files to be copied from there by other users except by a superuser or root for security issues. But need to work on those files by Netbeans or other IDE like it.

Can anyone help regarding this.

Comment: So you want to be able to edit the files but not allow users to copy them off the Samba share? What you're trying to do won't work because if a user can edit the files they have access to the data... nothing is stopping them doing "Save As..", copy and paste of the source code into, say, Notepad (I assume as you say Netbeans or other IDE) or doing a print screen of the file.

Answer (score -1):

Supposing your samba user has write/read permissions, do this:

```
chown -R sambauser:sambauser /your/protected/dir
```